# How to reset setting in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I don’t know what happen to my WebStorm settings but previously whenever I add new `react` component it gave me a warning by adding underline above the component name. But now it is not showing any warnings. Why?

Please see my screenshot example currently in screenshot function is not defined so it gives underline.

How to reset the setting?

[image]

In screenshot I added `Button,Dialog,DialogTitle` but not imported. It is not giving any warning, why?

Comment: Same on WebStorm forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000638440-Not-getting-error-when-component-is-not-imported-in-react

Comment: It could be that you've accidentally turned of an inspection.. open settings > search for inspections > go through the list (possibly "javascript imports" there is a subsearch in phpstorm at least)

Comment: Or it could be what they said ^ :)

Answer (score 1):

We intentionally decided not to mark the components as unresolved because there were quite a lot of patterns of defining the React components, especially in the component libraries that WebStorm couldn't recognize. So instead we decided to only show the missing import inspection for the cases where we knew where the component was defined.
We will review of how it all works now and will enable the inspection if it doesn't generate too much false positives.

Please vote for [WEB-32549](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32549) to be notified on any progress with this feature